# Constraing minimum height and width of outer div to the size of inner div

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a div within a div.

The outer div is draggable(jQuery) and the inner div is resizable(jQuery).

The inner div has a span within it which is filled with text.

How can I make the outer div height and width never be any smaller than the height and width of its contents?

Currently I can resize the outer div to be smaller and this is a problem when the outer div has a border as the text overflows out of the outer div.

thanks for your help in advance

Comment: it would be easy, if you provide jsfiddie source.

Comment: _"resizable(jQuery)"_ So you're using the jquery ui resizable plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a bit from each of your answers, this is how I solved it.

```
var spanminwidth=$('#span'+i).width();
spanminwidth=+spanminwidth+4;
$("#div"+i).css('min-width',spanminwidth);

var spanminheight=$('#span'+i).height();
spanminheight=+spanminheight+4;
$("#div"+i).css('min-height',spanminheight);
```

thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this, WithIn the resize event, 
1) Get the width of the inner div. And, 
2) Apply min-width of outer div as (innerdiv + 4) ..

so, whenever you resize, resize event will trigger, so, you need to get innerdiv width and set its outerdiv "min-width" slightly higher than innerdiv..

Hope this helps..

```
.bind('resize', function(){
      var outer_width = parseInt($('.innerdiv').width() + 4);
         $('.outerwidth').width(outer_width);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the min-height and min-width for the div which never get smaller.. For exact answer can you post your full html code.

Comment: The code is a mix of jquery javascript, html, css, php and sql so it would be difficult to cut up and post on here as a viewable cross section. I was just looking for some css or javascript that could constrain the outer div to the width and height of its contents

Comment: @BarryWatts after fixing the min-height and min-width. Can you able to  resize to smaller??

Answer (score 0):

Apply some `max-height` and `max-width` to the inner div.

If your outer div has 300px height and 300px width:

**inner div css**

```
max-height:300px;
max-width:300px;
```

Comment: the inner div is resizable with jQuery and so the max height is never determined

Comment: @Barry Watts So establish a maximum amount to resize, then do this

Comment: I want the user to be able to resize the inner div to whatever size they want, so max-height is not an option

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually using the jQuery UI Resizable plugin you can use [its own option parameters](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Resizable#option-minHeight):

```
$('.wrapper').resizable({
    minHeight: function() {
        $(this).contents().height();
    }
    ,minWidth: function() {
        $(this).contents().width();
    }
});
```